# Testing Equality of Variance - F test

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

[image]

### Notations:

- X, Y are random variable denoting nominal mass of a randomly selected packaged breakfast cereal from original & new machine respectively
- $X \sim N(\mu=296, \sigma^2)$
  $Y \sim N(\mu',\sigma^2)$
- This is a two sample one tail test.
- Use F test, assuming normal distribution and independence of populations.
- $n_X$ = $10$,
   $n_Y$ = $12$

### Processs:

- In the above question, the mean for original machine is given. Thus we can construct a standard normal rv followed by a chi square random variable as:
  $$ \sum_1^{n_X} (\frac{X_i - \mu}{\sigma})^2 \sim \chi^2_{n_X} $$
- For the second sample a chi square random variable is:
  $$ (n_Y-1)\frac{s^2_Y}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2_{n_Y-1} $$
- F distribution is given by ratio of two chi square random variables divided by their df, thus:
  $$ \frac{\sum_1^{n_X}(X_i - \mu)^2}{s^2_Y}\cdot \frac{1}{n_X} \sim F_{n_X,n_Y-1} $$

### Question:

- F statistic is given by:
  $$ \frac{s^2_X}{s^2_Y} \sim F_{n_X-1, n_Y-1} $$
- Through the above logic if i use $\mu$ to calculate $s^2_X$ then does the numerator df become $n_X$